# Not able to use Responsive event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I use DataTable with raw HTML.

Currently, I am trying to catch the `.on('responsive-display')` event.

This is my method:

I instantiate the DataTable in a file:

```js
$('#DataTables_Table_0').DataTable({
    responsive: {
        details: {
            type: 'column',
            target: 'tr'
        }
    }
});
```

In another file, I try to log when a row opens itself to reveal more content:

```js
$('#DataTables_Table_0').dataTable().api().on('responsive-display', function (e, datatable, row, showHide, update) {
    console.log('Details for row ' + row.index() + ' ' + (showHide ? 'shown' : 'hidden'));
});
```

In also tried:

```js
$('#DataTables_Table_0').DataTable().on('responsive-display', function (e, datatable, row, showHide, update) {
    console.log('Details for row ' + row.index() + ' ' + (showHide ? 'shown' : 'hidden'));
});
```

and

```js
$('#DataTables_Table_0').dataTable().on('responsive-display', function (e, datatable, row, showHide, update) {
    console.log('Details for row ' + row.index() + ' ' + (showHide ? 'shown' : 'hidden'));
});
```

When I click on a row to open it, it does not log anything. I think I'm using wrongly this plugin.

If you have any clue, please share it!

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/event/responsive-display#Example). `on()` is called on the DataTable reference, not the `api()` reference.

Comment: Hi, I tried without and edited my post accordingly.

Comment: `DataTable()`, not `dataTable()`. The two are not the same.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was coming from the fact that I did not set and use an `id` attribute on my table and used the DataTable generated one.